# How to override a method in Object Oriented Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I was trying to implement an `interface` like architecture in `JS` as followed in `C#`. And met with a stumbling block. Here is the code sample:

```
    // Interface for UIBuilder classes
    function IUIBuilder() {
        this.addUserToList = function () {
            alert('parent: added');
        };
    }

    // Class implementing the IUIBuilder
    function ChatUIBuider() {
        IUIBuilder.prototype.addUserToList = function () {
            alert('child: added');
        };
        IUIBuilder.prototype.removeUserFromList = function () {
            alert('child: removed');
        };

        return new IUIBuilder();
    }
```

In the first class, I've defined a method `addUserToList` which I override in the second class `ChatUIBuider`. Also added one more method `removeUserFromList` to the base class using its prototype.

My issue is, the `addUserToList` method still invokes the parent class method even after it has got overridden in the child class. Why?

```
    var builder = new ChatUIBuider();
    builder.removeUserFromList(); // Invokes the child class method. - CORRECT
    builder.addUserToList(); // Invokes the base class method- WHY??
```

Could anyone tell me if this is the correct way I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this construct :

```
function IUIBuilder() {
};
IUIBuilder.prototype.addUserToList = function () {
    alert('parent: added');
};

// Class extending the IUIBuilder
function ChatUIBuider() {
}
ChatUIBuider.prototype = new IUIBuilder();
ChatUIBuider.prototype.addUserToList = function () {
        alert('child: added');
};
ChatUIBuider.prototype.removeUserFromList = function () {
        alert('child: removed');
};
```

ChatUIBuider extends IUIBuilder and inherits its functions but overrides the `addUserToList` function.

In the following code, both constructors will be called but only the overriding `addUserToList` function will be called :

```
var chat = new ChatUIBuider();
chat.addUserToList();
```

See [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/F55ZJ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

@Denys restructured the entire code , without exactly pointing out the issue. issue is `addUserToList` is **not** a prototype method of your parent class , it's a `this` method which is copied for every instance and not sahred. So just converting it to a `prototype` method fixes the issue.

```
 // Interface for UIBuilder classes
    function IUIBuilder() {
    }
    IUIBuilder.prototype.addUserToList = function () {
            alert('parent: added');
    };

    // Class implementing the IUIBuilder
    function ChatUIBuider() {
        IUIBuilder.prototype.addUserToList = function () {
            alert('child: added');
        };
        IUIBuilder.prototype.removeUserFromList = function () {
            alert('child: removed');
        };

        return new IUIBuilder();
    }
    var builder = new ChatUIBuider();
    builder.removeUserFromList(); // Invokes the child class method. - CORRECT
    builder.addUserToList(); // Invokes the CHILD CLASS's METHOD
```